# How to improve symmetry in both strength and size

Tags: weightlifting, strength, muscle, workout, biceps

I have noticed lately that I lack symmetry in my arms (biceps and triceps, not forearms). This lack of symmetry also follows through to the strength and endurance in the weaker arm.

With my dominant hand (right), I have no issues with aesthetics and strength, however this does not translate across to my other arm. I have huge issues with the way the left arm looks and the strength issues that are starting to follow suit. I usually do exercises using barbells and some isolation exercises using drop sets on my pump week.

I would like to know:

- How could I improve the aesthetics or size of the weak side?
- How can I improve the strength in my weaker arm to get it up to a similar level as my dominant arm?

Comment: Do you do a lot of simultaneous lifts (right and left) at the same time? If so you should consider doing single arm lifts so your dominant arm can't affect your weaker.

Comment: I don't think this gets much more complex than "do some extra work with your weak arm". Maybe keep an eye out for activities in your everyday life that strengthen your right arm and ignore the left.

Comment: Have you checked out this question and answers about [left/right discrepancies](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6040/what-exercises-can-i-do-to-equalize-differences-in-upper-body-strength)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to focus on the weak arm. I am so right handed I can't stand it. When I am in the gym I have to make a very concerted effort to isolate my left arm. I have also noticed that my left arm has naturally formed bad habits from being my non-dominant hand. So when you focus on it, also concentrate on proper form. Don't shy away from doing tricep-dips, French-bar curls, etc. Just be extra conscious of the weaker arm.

Also be aware that everyone's body is different. My right deltoid muscles seem to have a noticeably shorter muscle belly than my left. Therefore my shoulders look asymmetrical. Even though my right shoulder is a little stronger than my left. Nothing I can do about it but try and accept the results.

Comment: decided on your answer due to you supplying the only answer - thank you